# Discord bot getting compromised, any way to whitelist IPs or view where recent post requests are coming from?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, bots

I have a discord bot that posts messages to a server i'm on.  Unfortunately the bot has now been compromised twice and spam messages are getting posted to the channel.

I'm not really sure how that is happening, i'm running ubuntu, and the bot key is only saved on netlify (my websites middleware via which the post requests are routed).

I've changed the auth token and it has happened again, and so I am trying to find out what I can do to track down the problem:

Can I view all the recent https post requests that have been made using the bot?  I'm not sure if that will tell me anything insightful... but maybe.

Ideally I would like to just whitelist my website so that only post requests that come from there are actually sent, is that possible with discord?  Or to have something in the header that the server can see to make sure that the post request is genuine?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!